# Host Java Server using Socket Communication

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, rmi, host

I need some guidance over here.

I managed to get my java server working, running a java thread listening for client socket communications, all the business logic is inside my java code.

I also managed to get multiple clients connected and everything went fine.
The clients use a Swing Application to connect with my Java Server, both the server and the client are individual java projects, .jar files.

Now I was looking to host the server on some free hosting environment, I already looked at Google App Engine, but it seems that it works only for servlets right?

Is it possible to turn accept tcp socket connection on servlets? I know that normally servlets are for HTTP connections, to show Java Server Pages for clients.

I also looked at RMI, Remote Method Invocation, but where can I host an RMI server?
I am looking for a free hosting, I dont need much bandwidth, 1GB is enough, maybe less..

There must be a service for what I am looking .

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a custom server of your own you're going to need VPS and those are not free. Some services such as Amazon have a [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) though so you can get started without extra costs.

Comment: I don't think you'll find RMI hosting either, so the cheapest option is VPS hosting.

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply, just a minor question, there is no chance using a servlet for the same purpose? Thanks ;)

Comment: Probably you can, you haven't said anything about what the server has to do to respond to requests. You'll have to change the communication protocol to work over HTTP though, so that instead of sending a message with your custom protocol or calling a remote method you send a HTTP request to a URL.

Comment: Hmm I see, now the connection is using sockets, custom objects of my application are serialized and transferred over the sockets.
I would need to change the code to use HTTP request and response, I got it :)  Thanks ;)